# Preprocessor definitions work in Release mode, not Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to get a preprocessor macro to be defined in one source file, hw_model.cpp, and leave it undefined in another, main.cpp.

When I run this program in x64 Release mode (Visual Studio 2017), everything is fine. When I run in x64 Debug mode, the #undef ACT_LIKE_HARDWARE  statement in main.cpp seems to be ignored.

model.h:

```
extern Signal signal;
void setSignalsFromHw();


// code below is inside some function :
#ifdef ACT_LIKE_HARDWARE
    // perform a procedure that behaves like hardware
    // This C code is supposed to act like hardware
    // hardware has the freedom to write to read-only variables
#else
    // perform some other procedure that firmware can normally do
#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#undef ACT_LIKE_HARDWARE

#include "model.h" 

Signals signal;

int main(){
    uint32_t read_data = signal.wv0;
    // do some processing on the read_data

    setSignalsFromHw();
}
```

hw_model.cpp:

```
#define ACT_LIKE_HARDWARE

#include "macro.h"

// Perform a cast on the "signal" global variable
// This cast operation is done so that "signal_HWModel" has the freedom to write to read-only fields
Signals_HWModel* signal_HWModel = reinterpret_cast<Signals*>(&signal);

void setSignalsFromHw(){
    ntfySignal_HWModel->wv0 = 0x2;
    ntfySignal_HWModel->wv1 = 0x4;
}
```

Firstly, should I be defining preprocessor macros in some source files, and undefining it in others? If not, what would be a good workaround? Please consider the fact that model.h is much more complicated than I protray it to be here and would be somewhat difficult to refactor, but I'm definitely open to all suggestions.

Secondly, why is there a distinction between running in debug vs. release mode?

Thanks

-------------- ** UPDATE ** --------------

As requested, this is the minimum, runnable code. It illustrates the same problem I had above. Sorry if it looks slightly different than the one above. I am just being careful not to reveal too much IP.

IMPORTANT: I am using the Google Test Framework, and the main() function that they provide. In Release, I am getting the expected behaviour (undef statement works and define statement works). In Debug, one of the preprocessor statements does not get hit.

test.cpp

```
#undef ACT_LIKE_HW

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "model.h"

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) {
    setSignalsFromHW();
    Block::assignSig();
}
```

hw_model.cpp

```
#define ACT_LIKE_HW
#include "model.h"

void setSignalsFromHW() {
    Block::assignSig();
}
```

model.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void setSignalsFromHW();

class Block {
    public:
        static void assignSig() {
        #ifdef ACT_LIKE_HW
            cout << "Performing hardware operations" << endl;
        #else
            cout << "Procedures that firmware usually executes" << endl;
        #endif
        }
};
```

However, if I create a brand new C++ project (that doesn't use Google Test, so it's a regular Console application), one of the preprocessor statements does not get hit for both Release and Debug, so that defeats the purpose of me defining those 2 preprocessor statements. I may just end up refactoring the code, but I would still like to know why this problem is happening with my Google Test Project.

Comment: Are you getting any warnings? Because likely you have undefined behavior if things are changing.

Comment: are you sure you do not define the macro only in the settings for release mode ?

Comment: Did you make sure to define `ACT_LIKE_HARDWARE` in both configurations? It is easy in the Visual Studio property panel to acidentally only set something on say "Active(Release)" or "Active(Win32)" instead of "All Configurations" and/or "All Platforms".

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. There could be hundreds of reasons behind your problem, but it's really impossible to do anything but guess with the information we currently have.

Comment: A [mcve] would probably show you have a ODR violation with two different functions with the same name depending on the define, only one copy is kept by the linker

Comment: @Mgetz yes. In Debug mode, I am specifically getting D9035 "option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future ...".  In both Debug and Release I am getting C4996 --> "Std::tr1" warning STL4002: The non-Standard std::tr1 namespace and TR1-only machinery are deprecated and will be REMOVED you can define _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING to acknowledge that you received this warning".

Comment: @bruno The release and debug config settings are the same in terms of preprocessor definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a One Definition Rule violation.

If you have multiple definitions of the same symbol in a program then your program has undefined behaviour if both definitions aren't identical.

Generally duplicate symbols are removed by the linker so only one of your functions will survive and both call sites will end up calling the same function.

If the function is inlined by the compiler then the code from the function is integrated into the calling function and the linker wont interfere so your code might work correctly. This is fragile though as when inlining doesn't happen in debug or when your function grows past the compilers size threshold for inlining it you'll get back to only having a single function again.

To fix it pass a boolean parameter to the function controlling which behaviour you want. If this function is inlined the compiler should delete the unused code branch.

Alternatively make the boolean parameter a template parameter and use `if constexpr` which will guarantee the deletion of the unused code.